# Working with input[type="text"] and input[type="checkbox"] in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I was working with checkboxes type input in the form. Just want to know the way I am handling it, Is it the right way or not?

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AiOutlineSearch } from "react-icons/ai";

import { useScroll } from '../custom_hook/useScroll';

const SearchBar = ({ totalPrograms, programs, setPrograms, isLoading }) => {

    const scrolled = useScroll();

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const searchProgramName = document.getElementById('search').value;
        
        if(searchProgramName) {
            setPrograms(
                programs.filter(program => 
                    program.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchProgramName)
                )
            );
        }
        else {
            handleClick();
        }
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        const allPhase = document.getElementsByName('phase');
        const checkedPhaseValue = [];

        allPhase.forEach(phase => {
            if(phase.checked) {
                checkedPhaseValue.push(phase.value);
            }
        });

        setPrograms(checkedPhaseValue.length ?
            totalPrograms.filter(
                program => checkedPhaseValue.includes(program.phase.toLowerCase())
            )
            : totalPrograms
        );
    }

    return (
        <header className={`container header header-sb ${scrolled && 'h-shadow'}`}>
            <form className="container container-center" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="type-search">
                    <AiOutlineSearch className="icon"/>
                    <input id="search" disabled={isLoading} type="search" placeholder="search by program name"/>
                </div>
                <div className="checkbox-container">
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled={isLoading} onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="open_application" value="application_open"/>
                        <label htmlFor="open_application">Open Application</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled={isLoading} onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="application_in_review" value="application_review"/>
                        <label htmlFor="application_in_review">Application in Review</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled={isLoading} onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="in_progress" value="in_progress"/>
                        <label htmlFor="in_progress">in Progress</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" disabled={isLoading} onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="completed" value="completed"/>
                        <label htmlFor="completed">Completed</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </header>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

The work I have to do is :

● Once the list is loaded, the user can now search through the page based on two
parameters:

1. The name of the program
2. Filter on the stage of the programs

● Once the user applies this filter+search then the page should pick out the programs
and show the result set (the filter is to be done on the front end and not a separate
server call)

Comment: If you just want to know if you are handling inputs correctly, then I would say no, you are not. There's no reason to query the DOM. You can query the search value from the form's `onSubmit` event and all inputs have an `onChange` event that you should be using instead of the `onClick` to get the input's `checked` and `value` values. You should really move all the state updating logic back to the parent component holding the state so it can maintain the state invariant and not rely on child components to do updates correctly.

Comment: I can use onChange instead of onClick, but you are saying I should not rely on child components to do updates correctly. My task is to filter the content based on the user choice (can be either through the checkboxes or the search value) on the front end and not a separate server call. So, My idea to handle this is, that I will store the whole content present at server in two arrays and when users want to filter, I will use one array to show content based on their choice and when they want to see whole programs, so instead of fetching I will use the second array to show the content.

Comment: https://github.com/hsnice16/beyond-boundaries/blob/master/src/pages/programsDirectory.js

Comment: *its parent component